# UWP Visual State Manager Change Grid Row Height

Tags: xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager, reflow

I am using a `VisualStateManager` in the XAML to specify a change in the width/height of a grid column/row by using the `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` `x:Name` properties. I read [here](https://metronuggets.com/2015/06/23/use-triggers-to-change-grid-columnrow-values-in-universal-windows-apps/) that this is possible... but Visual Studio says "Failed to find element named _____" with a warning, and the state change for the grid row does not work (the setters for changing row/column assignments trigger correctly, so I know the `VisualStateManager` is working overall).

The intended effect is to have the content vertically take up exactly the screen (with no vertical scrolling) in the wide state, with each block being in a different column. Then in the narrow state, the content will reflow to instead be all in the same column but different rows (thus vertically stacked), and thus vertical scrolling will be necessary (the content will also change from having a fixed width in the wide state, to stretching to take up the window width in the narrow state).

My code looks something like this:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockA.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockB.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockC.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockA.(Grid.Row)" Value="2"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockB.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentBlockC.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentRowZero.Height" Value="Auto"></Setter>
                        <Setter Target="ContentColumnZero.Width" Value="*"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="900"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!-- Empty setters defaults to the layout specified in XAML below. -->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ContentColumnZero"
                                      Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRowZero"
                                   Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Name="ContentBlockA"
                      Grid.Column="0">
                    <!-- Content here -->
                </Grid>

                <Grid Name="ContentBlockB"
                      Grid.Column="1">
                    <!-- Content here -->
                </Grid>

                <Grid Name="ContentBlockC"
                      Grid.Column="2">
                    <!-- Content here -->
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: For `VisualState` "narrow" can you set the `MinWindowWidth` to 1 and for the element for which the error shows up ("Failed to find element named _____" ) can you try removing the setter, rename the element and generate the visual state again from blend and see if it works ?

Comment: I don't use Blend. I wrote this XAML directly in Visual Studio.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I am asking you to use blend for now so that you can figure out what the difference between your code and the generated code is ..

Comment: Got it. I will try it out and see what it generates.

Comment: Any updates about this issue? Did you find out the reason?